# Save file with appropriate extension in a Save File prompt

Tags: c#, winforms, file-extension, savefiledialog

In my application I use a SaveFileDialog to pop up a Save As window. I have restricted in the file type section the file to be saved as .dat with the following code.

```
sfdialog.Filter = "Data Files (*.dat*)|*.dat*";
```

What I want to know how to do is make it automatically save with the .dat extension. Currently it just saves with no extension unless I specifically save it as filename.dat.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

```
SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();
dlg.Filter = "Data Files (*.dat)|*.dat";
dlg.DefaultExt = "dat";
dlg.AddExtension = true;
```

Answer (score 6):

The [AddExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.addextension.aspx) and [DefaultExt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.defaultext.aspx) properties. For example:

```
sfdialog.DefaultExt = "dat";
sfdialog.AddExtension = true;
```

Comment: It's important to note that `DefaultExt` is required, setting just the `Filter` and `AddExtension` is not enough by itself, which I found strange.